# Using LuaInterface - ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED

Tags: c#, dll, lua

I've been trying to integrate Lua into my managed code, using LuaInterface. I'm using the lua51.dll that came with the assembly I downloaded, but when I try to create a new Lua object, the constructor fails with ERROR_DLL_INIT_FAILED, or HRESULT 0x8007045A. I checked that I'm building as x86. What else can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Maybe you are mixing 32 bit and 64
   bit ?
2. Is it possible that you might have a
   different version in your path ?
3. Try running with elevated
   privileges.
4. Check your DLL with [Dependency
   Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way of solving this is...

Try to get a new Lua library here:

http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/

Test with this new one and see if the problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make **sure** you're compiling as 32bit, add x86 to your csproj file's .

I had a similar issue, but I would like to guess you're not as stupid as me to only think you're compiling as 32 bit when it's actually compiling as 64bit..